# How I can configure MS Graph API WithMaxRetry?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using MS Graph to return the list of users, I wanted to configure the amount of retries.

No matter what retry setting I put, it always returns that 4 attempts have been made.

This is my code.

```
internal async Task<Dictionary<Guid, UserListEntry>> GetAllAsync(Guid OrganizationId)
{
    var graphClient = graphServiceClientFactory.Create();

    var userRequest = graphClient.Users
        .Request()              
        .Filter($"{configSettings.FieldName} eq '{OrganizationId}'")
        .Select($"Id,DisplayName,Surname,Givenname,{configSettings.FieldName}");

    return await ProcessQuery(userRequest);
}


internal async Task<Dictionary<Guid, UserListEntry>> ProcessQuery(
    IGraphServiceUsersCollectionRequest userRequest
)
{
    var AllUsers = new List<UserListEntry>();

    do
    {
        var Results = await userRequest.WithMaxRetry(10).GetAsync();
        logger.LogInformation($"Method: {@userRequest.Method} Request:{@userRequest.RequestUrl}");

        PopulateUsers(AllUsers, Results);

        userRequest = Results.NextPageRequest;
    } while (userRequest != null);

    return AllUsers.ToDictionary(k => k.UserId);
}
```

This is the error message in the exception. Even with putting to do 10 retries.

> ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: Retry failed after 4
> tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry. (No such
> host is known.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look into the below link with a custom retry mechanism based on the http responses.

https://www.schaeflein.net/retrying-calls-to-the-microsoft-graph/